# Couchbase View Empty

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-view

I actually use couchbase with the java client, but when i query my view, the result is empty. But when i check the number of rows returned, it returns the good number of rows in the database :

```
ViewResult result = bucket.query(ViewQuery.from("logs", "all_logs"));
System.out.println("Number of rows " + result.totalRows() + " ; success " + result.success()); // Number of rows 12 ; success true
for (ViewRow row : result) {

    System.out.println("hello"); // never here
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

I try to do :

```
List<ViewRow> rows = result.allRows();
System.out.println("count : " + rows.size()); // count : 0
```

My view is in production mode.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm little confused by your code, when is `rows` defined?
What happens if you change `for (ViewRow row : rows) {` to `for (ViewRow row : result) {` This is the example from the [Couchbase Java SDK](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/querying-views.html).

Comment: Sorry, the rows is from List<ViewRow> rows = result.allRows(); I tried the couchbase java sdk example, same problem, count = 12 but when i do " for (ViewRow row : result) {" result is empty.

Comment: try creating different view, or use one that comes with brewery sample bucket.

Comment: @Arthe Can you upload your view code please?

Comment: @arthe - any updates here?